# How to monitor for lack of Lambda invocation in AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We've ran into issues where lambdas don't end up running when we expect them to, whether triggered from a Cloudwatch Rule or some other source. I'd like to configure a Cloudwatch Alarm to alert me if a lambda doesn't run in an expected time period.

My first pass was to create the following alarm (for a lambda I expect to run once per day):

`sum(invocations) < 1 for time period of 1 day`

The problem with this is that if the lambda never gets invoked, it never generates a data point in Cloudwatch Metrics, and consequently the alarm stays in an `insufficient data` state.

I'm thinking I could write a separate lambda that would use `boto3` to find the timestamp on the most recent logstream for the lambda in question and use some logic to determine if it's running properly or not - but this seems like a ridiculous solution.

Is there a way to implement this properly in Cloudwatch Alarms?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is sum registers 0 as no data points. thus alarm goes to "Insufficient Data" state rather than "In Alarm" state. 
As a work around, you can do the following:

*1. goto "Missing data treatment" section inside Alarm, then choose:
 2. "Treat missing data as bad(breaching thresold)"*

This should set the state in Alarm state, when you have 0 invocation within 24hrs.

Answer (score 0):

Having spent around half a day looking to solve the same problem, I've come to the conclusion that it's not possible to solve this using only CloudWatch. We've had to make do with an INSUFFICIENT_DATA state to highlight a lack of invocation.